# Attempting to print in C when creating functions

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am running this code, and the print commands are not actually resulting in any printing. Can anyone please advise? I do have a couple of comments at the end that will preface my two other functions, but for now, I am just interested in knowing why the prints aren't appearing even though my code doesn't show any errors.

Thanks!

```
# include <cs50.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int length(long number);
int start_chars(long number);

//Main
int main (void)
{
    long number = get_long("Number: ");
    int length(long number);
    int start_chars(long number);
}

//Number length count
int length(long number)
{
    int len = 0;
    do
    {
        len ++;
        number /= 10;
    }
    while (number > 0);
    return len;
    printf("Length: %d", len);
}

//Number first characters
int start_chars(long number)
{
    long charsnum = number;
    while (charsnum >= 100)
    {
        charsnum /= 10;
    }
    return charsnum;
    printf("First 2 digits: %ld", charsnum);
}

//Length & character count congruity

//Checksum
```

Comment: Because those statements are after the `return` statement

Comment: A good IDE will warn you about unreachable statements like that.

Comment: Aside: please add a newline to the end of the output when you are debugging, so that the message isn't left in a buffer - or all head to tail ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is terminated immediately after the `return` statement.

Your printing statement is after the return statement in those functions. That is why, they don't appear when you run the code.

So, put them before the return statement and you should be able to see them in the output. Moreover, for some clean output, do use `\n` inside those `printf`.

Then, inside your `main` function, look at these statements:

```
int length(long number);
int start_chars(long number);
```

Those are function declarations and not how [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) are called in C. Store the return value in a variable. Since you just want to see those `printf` statements get executed, change that to:

```
length(number);
start_chars(number);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the part about calling functions properly!

Answer (score 0):

when you use `return` in your functions they will end immediately.

and so your `printf` line won't be executed.

`printf` should be before `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answers above, you made an error in your code where you are printing after the return statement.

Here is the correct code :

```cpp
# include <cs50.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int length(long number);
int start_chars(long number);

//Main
int main (void)
{
    long number = get_long("Number: ");
    int length(long number);
    int start_chars(long number);
}

//Number length count
int length(long number)
{
    int len = 0;
    do
    {
        len ++;
        number /= 10;
    }
    while (number > 0);
    printf("Length: %d", len);
    return len;
}

//Number first characters
int start_chars(long number)
{
    long charsnum = number;
    while (charsnum >= 100)
    {
        charsnum /= 10;
    }
    printf("First 2 digits: %ld", charsnum);
    return charsnum;
}

//Length & character count congruity

//Checksum
```

Comment: I tried this, and still having the same issue upon recompiling. Any clue what might be going on?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @KhaledNassra what problem did you have exactly